# why is it necessary to calculate hash based on difficulty in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

for example if a certain block requires certain 5 leading zeros then can't we write a 32 byte random hash which has 5 leading zeroes like

```
00000C66DA510B7C524F7EF33279BCA641E2E8BF94B6B15AC6343CD2B706F673
```

or

```
00000C66DA510B7C524F7EF33279BCA641E2E8BF94B6B15AC6343CD2ASDFERTY
```

Also, if i am designing my own blockchain,then will choosing any random number without hashing make a difference in security of the blockchain?

Comment: The point of finding a hash with x leading zero-bits is to make it hard. Creating a random string with x leading zeros isn't hard at all.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `R`, `S`, `T`, and `Y` are not hexadecimal values either.

Comment: Does it effects the overall security of the blockchain?

Comment: Yes, and its pointless. You could just use the hash and not require any leading zero bits if you don't care about the cost-factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *choose* the hash of a blockchain block.  Each block has some data (including the hash of the previous block), and then a "nonce", and then a cryptographic hash of the whole thing.  One of the essential design properties of a cryptographic hash is that nobody knows how to choose the input to make the output come out a particular value.

What a blockchain miner does all day is compute `HASH(prev_hash || new data || 1)`, `HASH(prev_hash || new data || 2)`, `HASH(prev_hash || data || 3)`, ... until they reach a number that makes the hash come out with the required number of leading zeroes.  That's the work that they are proving they have done.  And then they publish the block, with its nonce and hash, and it takes only a trivial amount of work by comparison to *verify* that `HASH(prev_hash || new data || n)` has the required number of leading zeroes, so the block is accepted.

Proof of work is not a mandatory feature of a blockchain, and in fact it would be really nice if we could figure out a good alternative, because proof of work is what makes Bitcoin consume as much electricity as the entire country of Sweden or whatever it's up to these days.  A blockchain is just a sequence of blocks of data, chained together with cryptographic hashes and signatures.  What proof-of-work does - what including the "hash must have so many leading zeroes" rule does - is make it difficult for someone to control *which miner* will successfully mine the next block, and that is argued to mean "no one individual can force the distributed system to accept *their* next block instead of someone else's."

If some of the assertions in the previous paragraph seem a bit, um, shaky to you, you are absolutely correct.  That is why cryptocurrency is still a field of active research rather than something everyone uses all the time.